# Magento 2 new steup installation error

Tags: magento2, error, installation

what can I do?

```
[ERROR] LogicException: Unknown module in the requested list: 'Magento_BundleSampleData' in /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php:469
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(428): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->readListOfModules(Array, Array, 'enable-modules')
#1 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(358): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->createModulesConfig(Array, true)
#2 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Controller/Install.php(109): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->install(Array)
#3 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(84): Magento\Setup\Controller\Install->startAction()
#4 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Controller/AbstractController.php(118): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#7 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/DispatchListener.php(118): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#8 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(322): Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-eventmanager/src/EventManager.php(179): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#10 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Application.php(340): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerEventUntil(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#11 /home/sd378070/gigatyre.com/www/magento2/setup/index.php(39): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#12 {main}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time these type of errors come when you try to install magento2 previously and it was failed due to some reason.

and you have started your installation process again after removing all of the previous installed files and removed old database entry.

So, to overcome this issue, before starting your installation process, just remove your browser's cookie.

Thanks.

Comment: thank you! its work